# Need help with converting or analyzing uneven time intervals

Tags: time-series, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have next to no idea what I'm doing.

I have unevenly sampled poll data over an 11 year time period and a database of events. I wish to show whether or not increases in the number of these events correlate to increases in the percentage of affirmative poll responses (the poll's responses are ranked "very," "not very," "not too" and "not at all," I'm lumping the first two together as affirmative and the latter as negative).

Dates of the polls: http://puu.sh/1rj6l

How would one go about converting this unevenly collected poll data to a normal time series? As you can see, there are some points where the polls are very close together and some where they are a year or so apart. Is it viable to convert it like this? The final interval doesn't much matter - what I'm doing is summing the number of events since the last interval and seeing how changes in that number correlate to changes in people's responses.

I have Excel and SPSS at my disposal.

Answer (score -1):

Check out modelling with a Poisson distribution. It's used for analysing event rates.

Comment: I was considering simplifying the entire ordeal - my goal is to demonstrate a relationship between the frequency of the events and the polling results, and the issue is that the polls were taken at such irregular intervals. Could I reasonably just divide the number of events by the number of days since the last poll and plot the poll data against the number of attacks/day in a simple scatterplot and avoid this problem?

Comment: So I did just that and found the Spearman coefficient. Is there anything else I would have to do in this situation?